# splitting a list into multiple columns

Tags: list, split

I have a file that has two columns. the first column has a comma separated list of values, and the 2nd column has a single list of values. I would like to split the file up so the first column (each comma separated value) is on it's own line, and the 2nd column is with each corresponding value in the first column. so here is an example:

> foo,boo,zoo   10

I would like this to look like this:

foo 10

boo 10

zoo 10

splitting the comma first column is simple, I'm struggling with adding the 2nd column to each line.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What OS are you using?  What tools or editor?

Comment: just doing this in linux. I was thinking of some "simple" awk command. but have hit a roadblock..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk, first set the field separator to a space.  Then split the first column into an array named 'a'.  Loop through each element, printing it followed by the second column.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" "} {n=split($1,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i], $2}' file.txt
foo 10
boo 10
zoo 10
```